# Puppet client source class files

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to somehow find the source files of the applied Puppet classes of a client?

I have access to a server that is managed by Puppet and would like to take a peek inside the source class files to learn from them. I already managed to get a list of all the applied classes with `cat $(puppet config print classfile)`, but I cannot find any *.pp files on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a master - agent setup, the Puppet classes are not available on the agent, the agent requests a catalog of "how the system should look", and then applies it.

This can include using locally cached Ruby code, which are pulled by "plugin sync" to a local directory, only readable by root/puppet. Either `/var/lib/puppet` or `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache`.

Here are a few resources:

- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/architecture.html
- https://puppet.com/blog/starting-puppet-basics-from-a-puppet-labs-employee/
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/puppet_index.html